# How to compile liblwgeom independently?

Tags: spatialite

For using liblwgeom function in spatialite, I need to compile the library. I found that it is included in the PostGIS code.

My question is, how to compile the library without compiling the whole PostGIS?

Comment: What type of system are you trying to build spatialite on?

Comment: 64 bit ubuntu 11.10

Comment: Are you looking for GEOS (the geometry library that powers spatialite and and postgis)

Comment: No, liblwgeom is another library provided by PostGIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be an easier way, but one option:

- get source code for postgis (svn or recent tarball)
- make sure you have dependencies (e.g. install postgres devel packages, or just do aptitude build-dep postgis)
- ./autogen.sh (if using svn checkout)
- ./configure --without-raster --without-topology
- check results, fix as required
- cd liblwgeom
- make
- sudo make install if required