# spatialite - azimuth function not available

Tags: spatialite, ubuntu, windows, azimuth

I am working with last spatialite versions on both Windows (7) and Ubuntu (13.10).

I installed these from [reference spatialite website](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/). For both, version that I downloaded is 4.1.1 (nevertheless in Ubuntu, at spatialite start up, i get a version number : 4.1.0 ; I assume this is a little bug)

Details on the packages :

- binaries for windows: spatialite-4.1.1-win-x86.zip
- source for ubuntu: libspatialite-4.1.1.tar.gz and all other usefull ressources

I then developped a sql script on windows, notably using azimuth /st_azimuth
this works fine on this OS. I have problems when I use it on Ubuntu and get the following error:

```
no such function: Azimuth
```

after some search, I undesrtood that [this could be related](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=switching-to-4.0#liblwgeom) to a missing lib: liblwgeom.

I had some more search to get this lib installed properly (at least no error message at the end) using the procedure described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48495/how-to-compile-liblwgeom-independently) (I effectively did the make and make install), but this does not seem to help.

Questions:

- is the "wrong" version number for spatialite 4.1.1 a known bug?
- is the missing Azimuth a know problem (i could not find any info)
- is installing liblwgeom the solution to my probleùm ?
- how to know if the liblwgeom install properly working ?
- what may I have missed in the process ?

Thanks for your help and pieces of advice

Comment: So the only way to get a working copy of Spatialite with liblwgeom support enabled is by compiling the code? There is no way to enable liblwgeom support by using (say) Ubuntugis packages?

Answer (score 7):

Answer from Sandro Fueri, posted on the spatialite users group
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spatialite-users/wx0RAFTA2tM

> Hi Pascal,
>
> the most recent versions of SpatiaLite support several interesting 
>   "advanced" functions based on LWGEOM: ST_Azimuth(), ST_MakeValid(), 
>   ST_Split() and so on.  anyway enabling or not LWGEOM is a configurable
>   option; and the  default setting is --disable-lwgeom=yes  (i.e. always
>   disable LWGEOM, if not explicitly required)
>
> the liblwgeom library is a self-standing independent module, but  it
>   isn't directly available as such.  it is integral part of PostGIS, and
>   the unique supported way to  get liblwgeom installed (or built) is the
>   one to install (or build)  a very recent version of PostGIS (v.2.0 or
>   v.2.1)
>
> if you wish to get a full fledged version of libspatialite-4.1.1  on
>   any Linux system you have to accomplish the following steps: 
>   - install (or build) PostGIS 2.x 
>   - install (or build) libxml2 
>   - configure and then build libspatialite-4.1.1 by enabling both     lwgeom and libxml2
>
> ./configure --enable-lwgeom=yes --enable-libxml2=yes  make  sudo
>   make-install
>
> PLEASE NOTE WELL: liblwgeom is released under the GPL licence;  due to
>   cross-license constraints, building libspatialite with  liblwgeom
>   enabled make libspatialite (and any further sw depending  on
>   libspatialite) to become implicitly GPLed.
>
> bye Sandro

Comment: Looks like liblwgeom has been replaced by librttopo in newer versions of spatiliate.

Answer (score 5):

If you have to use an older version of spatialite, here is the SQL equivalent for the postgis ST_Azimuth(A,B):

```
case
    when X(A) == X(B) then case
        when Y(A)  Y(B) then 3.141592653589793
        else 0
        end
    when Y(A) == Y(B) then case 
        when X(A)  X(B) then 3.141592653589793 + 3.141592653589793/2
        else 0
        end
    when X(A)  Y(B) then atan( abs(X(A) - X(B)) / abs(Y(A) - Y(B)) ) + 3.141592653589793
        else atan( abs(Y(A) - Y(B)) / abs(X(A) - X(B)) ) + 3.141592653589793 + 3.141592653589793/2
        end
    end
```

Not completely equivalent since it won't return an error if A==B.