# ST_MakeValid is not working?

Tags: qgis, python, spatialite

I have a polyline spatialite database, tried to perform repair geometry in QGIS using python with the following code:

```
from pyspatialite import dbapi2 as db

conn = db.connect(r'D:\db.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

repairGeometry = "UPDATE the_table SET GEOMETRY = ST_MakeValid(GEOMETRY) WHERE ST_IsValid(GEOMETRY) = 0;"
rs = cur.execute(repairGeometry)
```

I am getting this error:

```
rs = cur.execute(repairGeometry)
OperationalError: no such function: ST_MakeValid
```

Answer (score 2):

Error means that your program is compiled with such Spatialite version that does not have ST_MakeValid function. Only way to fix is to recompile with a proper version. Notice that ST_MakeValid is a LWGEOM function so Spatialite must be compiled accordingly with liblwgeom. Notice also that liblwgeom is using GPL license.

If you can't compile yourself as a workaround you can fix the database with a recent spatialite-gui which does have ST_MakeValid.

Comment: The version what i have is SQLite v3.7.17 Spatialite v4.1.1. Can you please assist how to compile spatialite version?

Comment: The short manual is at http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/linux_how_to.html. If I can read it right lwgeom is configured by default if user does not turn it off https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/artifact/6e3952e40540961e7d49d27d8be6d40bf3bf390c

Comment: Related response: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/88418/46142

Comment: Looks like liblwgeom has been replaced by librttopo in newer versions of spatiliate.